# How is Parseval’s theorem applied on this equation?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am reading a paper and the paper mentioned the Parseval’s theorem. I googled a lot and I can't find how is the theorem apllied to the equation. The following is the confusing part of the paper.

[image]

How can I get equation 8 from equation 7?

Thanks

Comment: If $f,g\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, then $\int f g^*dx = \int \hat{f}\hat{g}^* dx$, which follows from $\int |f|^2dx =\int |\hat{f}|^2 dx$ by the polarization identity.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem (Parseval and Plancherel are often used interchangeably in the literature).